# Symfony I want to send form with many select with some name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I created form with many select generate with for

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id='from_quantity' name="from_quantity">
{% for PanierProduct in PanierProducts %}
<input type="hidden" name="idProduct" value="{{PanierProduct.id}}">
{% for i in 1..eReservation.ereservationmaxquantity %}
<option value="{{ i }}" {% if i == panier[PanierProduct.id] %} selected ="seleted" {% endif %}>{{ i }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

and in the jquery i use this code for send my form and it's work very good

```
$("#ConfirmQuantity").click(function(){
var url = Routing.generate('front_office', {baseDomaine : baseDomaineJS , _locale: 'en'});alert(data);
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: $("#from_quantity").serialize(),
           url: url,
           success: function (data) { 
                alert(data);
            }
         })
          ;
});
```

the problem new how can I receive this form in the controller I try many Proposal and no one work for exemple here i wan to get the all form but it doesn't work:

```
$form = $request->request->get('from_quantity');
$responce = new JsonResponse();
return $responce->setData(array('res' => $form));
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller put
`$this->getRequest()->request->all();`
In there you have array with all POST variables.

You have mistake in generates your form. You should use array as element name.

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id='from_quantity' name="from_quantity">
{% for PanierProduct in PanierProducts %}
<input type="hidden" name="idProduct[]" value="{{PanierProduct.id}}">
{% for i in 1..eReservation.ereservationmaxquantity %}
<option value="{{ i }}" {% if i == panier[PanierProduct.id] %}
selected="seleted" {% endif %}>{{ i }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

When want get all element:

`$arr = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
 foreach($arr as $row) {}`

When want get first element:

`$element = $arr[0];`

Comment: and how can i get the first element of this array ??